# how to send http request through perl script to weblogc server

Tags: perl, http

There is a requirement to check the status of the webservice running on weblogic. The web service runs in the background and doesnt have HTML page to laucch though browsers. However it responds to HTTP queries along with the request type.

I need to send the request say  and it responds with the corrosponding status code. The problem is there is no frame or web page to type the request. The request has to be sent programmatically. Can this be done using perl?

I tried using LWP module but couldnt get the desired results,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$PARAM = "<HealthCheck>" ;

my $req = (POST '[http://host_name:8080/service]' ["xmlString" => $PARAM]);
$request = $ua->request($req); 
$content = $request->content; 

print $content; 
exit;
```

Please help.

Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible, just change the syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $PARAM = "<HealthCheck>" ;

my $response = $ua->post('http://host_name:8080/service', {'xmlString' => $PARAM}); 
if( $response->is_success ) {
   print $response->decoded_content;
}
else {
   print STDERR $response->status_line, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel... it works after few changes specific to my requirements. Thanks again